# three.js installation for running basic tutorial example

Tags: javascript, module, three.js

This is a three.js setup question (on Safari, MacOS Catalina).

As suggested by threejs.org:

```
  % brew install node
  % npm install three
  % ls -sF node_modules/three/build   # shows the right things: three.js, three.module.js etc.
```

then in my .html file:

```
  ...
  <script type="module" src="./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js"> </script>
  <script>
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  ...
```

First error: used THREE.scene() instead of THREE.Scene().  Fixed.

Second error: used node-modules with - not _ in the local file pathname. Fixed.

Third error: needed to turn on Safari Develop menu (Safari->Preferences->Advanced->Show Develop menu in menu bar). Fixed.

Fourth error: Cannot access local file. Fixed by Safari->Develop->Disable Local File Restrictions.

Fifth error: used "src="node_modules/three/build/three.module" without final ".js", following another Stack Overflow answer to a related question. Fixed by using .js suffix which is the accurate file path.

Sixth error: Tried skipping the import statement.  Results in "Can't find variable THREE." Fixed by reverting to including the import statement.  But that's not actually a fix is it.

Seventh error: tried prefixing * with \ as in "import * ..." as suggested somewhere. Error generated; reverted.

Eighth attempt: tried

```
 <script type="importmap"> { "imports": { "three": "./path_to_three.module.js" } } </script>
 <script type="module"> import * as THREE from 'three'; </script>
 <script> const scene = new THREE.Scene(); ...
with error "Can't find variable THREE"
```

Ninth, tenth, etc., attempts (with CDNs instead of NPM's locally-installed three.js tree):

```
<script async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r99/three.module.min.js">
</script>

or 

<script async src="https://cdn.skypack.dev/three"></script>

or

<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
<script type="importmap"> { "imports": 
   { "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.142.0/build/three.module.js" } } </script>
<script type="module"> import * as THREE from 'three'; </script>
<script> const scene = new THREE.Scene(); ...

Each of these generate the error: "Can't find variable THREE"
```

Isn't there a nice easy reliable way to incorporate the three.js library and namespace so that the first API call in the first most basic tutorial example can actually run successfully?  You would think with all these sites supporting it, and tutorials and Q&A's purporting to answer the question how to use three.js, there would be some good answer out there.  I haven't found it.  What works for you?

Comment: "As suggested by threejs.org" — Three.js doesn't teach  you how to use those build tools. Only use that approach if you're already using them or if you learn how to use them (specifically for client-side web development) first.

Comment: the last example worked fine when I tested it

Comment: Right, and it's been a slog to get npm working. I had to change ISPs (GoDaddy/Google to Linode, which allows me to install and use Node on my web server. On my development Mac too, it was, learn HomeBrew, brew install node (which gets you npm). npm install three, all  admin stuff, and then this bit about how to refer to a local module file from within a local .html page.  Apparently having src= in one script tag and import * in another script's code was an error.  I.e., don't use multiple <script> tags, in this case.  I wonder what's the true generaliation

Answer (score 0):

I found the following steps resulted in the console and file errors going away.

1. DO Install locally (npm install three; creates ./node_modules/.../three*js)
2. DO NOT use a module include-by-reference script as in `<script type="module" src="https:..."></script>` or `<script type="module" src="./path-to-file.module.js"></script>`
3. DO use a type="module" annotation on your main script's <script..> tag.
4. DO NOT use a src=path annotation in your main script  tag.
5. DO use the local path in an import statement in your main script.

Summarizing:

```
<script type="module">
  import * as THREE from './node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
  const scene = new THREE.Scene()
  console.log("Success.  scene = " + scene);
</script>
```

Hopefully that may help others.